# Django form returns method as GET instead of POST

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I've set method='POST' but print(request.method) in my view prints GET and I don't know why, so my button won't work and save the data,
I have tried everything i know but my code doesn't get fix

This my template where I have set method as POST in form tag and also I have set action of form with the url, I have also set formmethod as POST in button tag:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="card m-b-30">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{% url 'create_production' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="p-20">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>تاریخ</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text cursor-pointer" id="tdate"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    {{ form.date }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>نام شرکت</label>
                                {{ form.comName }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label></label>
                                {{ form.comId }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>نام محصول</label>
                                {{ form.prodName }}
                            </div>      
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label></label>
                                {{ form.prodId }}
                            </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="p-20">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label></label>
                                {{ form.gradeId }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>نام گرید</label>
                                {{ form.gradeName }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>نوع گرید</label>
                                {{ form.gradeType }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>تولید</label>
                                {{ form.qty }}
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="p-20">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>ظرفیت</label>
                                {{ form.cap }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>ظرفیت طراحی</label>
                                {{ form.designCap }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>برنامه</label>
                                {{ form.plan }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>واحد</label>
                                {{ form.unit }}
                            </div>              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" formmethod="POST" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">تایید</button>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my views.py, code won't run the first if condition:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['editor'])
def create_production(request):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comId = Company.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).get(userId=request.user)
        form = CreateProduction(request.user, comId, request.POST)    
        if form.is_valid():
            production = form.save(commit=False)
            production.user = request.user
            production.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        comId = Company.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).get(userId=request.user)
        form = CreateProduction(request.user, comId)
    return render(request, 'production/production_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: try to replace `type="button"` with `type="submit"` for submitting the form

Comment: tried it but didn't work

Comment: Replace your button with this: <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So i used input tag instead of button with type equal to submit and it worked